# Rails added model attribute not filling from form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes

I added an attribute to a model. The form field populates, but when I submit, it doesn't input it into my DB.

The field is RoleID:

[image]

You can see on the next page that it does not fill the DB:

[image]

I have also confirmed from the DB:

```
+----+--------+-------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | userid | email                   | password | fname   | lname | created_at          | updated_at          | roleids |
+----+--------+-------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 |      1 | kendallweihe@gmail.com  | test     | kendall | weihe | 2016-03-15 21:56:30 | 2016-03-15 21:56:30 |    NULL |
|  2 |      2 | kendall.weihe@gmail.com | test     | ken     | weihe | 2016-03-16 11:39:05 | 2016-03-16 11:39:05 |    NULL |
|  3 |      2 | kendall.weihe@gmail.com | test     | ken     | weihe | 2016-03-16 11:42:32 | 2016-03-16 11:42:32 |    NULL |
|  4 |      2 | kendall.weihe@gmail.com | test     | ken     | weihe | 2016-03-16 11:44:26 | 2016-03-16 11:44:26 |    NULL |
+----+--------+-------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

The input form looks like this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :roleids, "RoleID: 1 for Employee or 2 for Customer" %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :roleids %>
    <%debugger%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

The debugger placed above confirms that the attribute exists:

```
#<User id: nil, userid: nil, email: nil, password: nil, fname: nil, lname: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, roleids: nil>
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is frequently due to strong params, do you use them? Can you post the relevant parts of your controller?

Comment: What is in the `user_params` method? @Matt is right, the simplest error would be that you've forgotten to add `roleids` to the `user_params` method.

Comment: @j-dexx that was it!

Answer (score 1):

check you have added `roleids` attribute to your strong parameter in your controller like:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :fname, :lname, :roleids)
end
```